# E-Reader for PDF files optimized for printing

Tags: displays, e-reader, e-ink

I am looking for an E-Reader for reading scientific articles. The main difficulty I see here is, that most E-Readers seem to be optimzed for viewing scalable ePub files. However I need a device which is able to quickly render complex PDF pages with smaller font sizes and complex figures.

So, to sum it all up, I need a device with a large display in order to keep the font size readable when displaying a whole page on the one hand and on the other hand a device which is fast enough to render complex PDF pages in an acceptable speed.

One option I am still not sure about is the kind of display: I am a great fan of energy-saving eInk displays; but are there some who are able to display colors? So, I am looking for a recommendation and eventually experience reports, if available. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "fast enough to render complex PDF pages" is definitely not a problem.  But the question is, do you prefer a large display, or a color display?  As far as I'm aware, you can't have both.